# MySQL Syntax Error - Extra eyes?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Can someone run their eyes over this statement? I keep getting a syntax error and I'm stumped as to what is wrong.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO emails (to, from, subject, content, ip) VALUES('$email_to', '$email_from', '$subject', '$content', '$ip' ) ")
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''to', 'from', subject, content, ip) VALUES('[MY EMAIL ADDRESS]', 'l', 'hi', ' at line 1
```

EDIT 2:

I have sanitized.

```
$email_to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_to']);
$email_from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_from']);
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
```

Comment: what is the error message that you are receiving.

Comment: It's very difficult to find a SQL syntax error without the real query and the error message.

Comment: Syntax errors aside, it's a really bad idea to let someone do SQL injection attacks by sending you email.

Comment: Sorry, I'll put the error message in, but it is just generic. Marco solved it.

Comment: @Wooble I am escaping the user-submitted code earlier in the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO emails (`to`, `from`, subject, content, ip) 
    VALUES('$email_to', '$email_from', '$subject', '$content', '$ip' )")
```

I think the error raises because `from` is a reserved word... backticks should solve this problem.
Remember you **MUST** always sanitize user input to avoid SQL injection!!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this. What are the words reserved for?

Comment: @Sam: reserved works are (te tell you in a simple way) the ones database engine build its query language with. Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @Sam:  tobyodavies is right, you MUST always sanitize user input to avoid SQL injection !!!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps escape the 'from' field, as from is a keyword;